# Capturing an Android Camera Stream over USB with C/C++ and libusb

Tags: c++, c, android-camera, adb, libusb

I've done some research on this and have already tried using IP WebCam and gstreamer to pipe the video stream from the IP based source to `/dev/videoX` and reading from that.

It works fine, but it isn't exactly what I am looking for.  I have several old useless phones that I would like to use on a robot as video sources from multiple angles for computer vision based tasks.

I've also read that DroidCam does this, but I have read terrible reviews about the app and especially the USB based part.

Most likely this robot will not be near any WiFi (or rather should not require it), and the phones will not have a network connection (no SIM card), so no USB tethering.

It seems like there should be a very simple way to do this.  Is there a way to use`libusb` and maybe `adb` to capture the video stream from an Android phone connected to an Ubuntu box with USB?

Comment: [USB tunnelling?](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191930/Android-Usb-Port-Forwarding)

Comment: I don't think there is, not for realtime video. I once did something like this: https://medium.com/@elye.project/capture-picture-and-record-video-using-adb-5f4c582acb3c and managed to get 3 frames per second, or was is 1 frame every 3 seconds ... *lol*. Can't remember. Video can be recorded too, but as it says in the link, it only records to a local file on memory card. Maybe you can stick Ethernet on the phones, but that's a bundle of money and rats nest of cables: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/otg-list-usb-to-ethernet-rj45-adapters-t3530677